# VB script to scan latest log file for errors

Tags: vbscript

I have a VB script which scans the mentioned log file for errors and sends a notification through an email.

How can I scan the latest log file in the folder? For example, `Filename1.070615` (`Filename1.mmddyy`) is a log file. After a certain size, the logfile switches to new file with the same name but different date: `Filename1.070615`.

```
    cdoSendUsingPort = 2, _

Const ForReading = 1

Dim intStartAtLine, strFileCreateddate, i, strResults, strTextToScanFor, bStartFromScratch
Dim strLastCheckedFor, strArrayToString, strSubject, strMailFrom, strMailTo

 strMailto               = "<Emailaddress>"


strMailFrom     = "<FromAddress>"      

strSubject              = "Log scanner"


strSMTPServer   = "x.x.x.x"    

FileToRead              = "D:\LOG\filename1.mmddyy"

arrTextToScanFor        = Array("error","another thing")

Set WshShell            = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

searchkey                       = replace(replace(filetoread,":",""),"\","_")

On Error Resume Next
strLastFileCheckedCreateDate    = WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\RDScripts\CheckTXTFile\" & searchkey & "\CreateDate")
strLastFileLastLineChecked              = WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\RDScripts\CheckTXTFile\" & searchkey & "\LastLineChecked")
strLastCheckedFor                               = WshSHell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\RDScripts\CheckTXTFile\" & searchkey & "\CheckForString")
iLastCheckedLine                                = WshSHell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\RDScripts\CheckTXTFile\" & searchkey & "\LastLineChecked")
On Error GoTo 0

Set objFSO                                              = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set varFile                                     = objFSO.GetFile(FileToRead)

arrLastCheckedForText                   = split(strLastCheckedFor,",")
strFileCreateDate                               = varfile.datecreated
strFileModifiedDate                             = varfile.datelastmodified

sStatus                                                 = "<li>Using mail server: " & strSMTPServer & "</li><li>Running from: " & wscript.scriptfullname & "</li>"

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileToRead, ForReading)
objTextFile.ReadAll

    iLineCount = objTextFile.Line

objTextFile.close


    If strLastCheckedFor = "" Then
        bStartFromScratch = true
        sStatus = sStatus & "<li>First run of script against string search</li>" & vbcrlf

ElseIf ubound(arrTextToScanFor) <> ubound(arrLastCheckedForText) Then
        bStartFromScratch = true
        sStatus = sStatus & "<li>Count of string search criteria has changed</li>" & vbcrlf
Else
        For each strItem in arrTextToScanFor
                                    Else   
                        bStartFromScratch = true

                        'MsgBox strResults
                End If

                If bStartFromScratch = true Then
                        sStatus = sStatus & "<li>String search criteria does not match prior search</li>" & vbcrlf
                End If

        Next
End If
If cint(iLineCount) < cint(iLastCheckedLine) Then      
        bStartFromScratch = true
        sStatus = sStatus & "<li>Last line checked (" & iLastCheckedLine & ") is greater than total line count (" & iLineCount & ") in file</li>"

End If

If CStr(strFileCreateDate) = CStr(strLastFileCheckedCreateDate) and bStartFromScratch <> true Then

        intStartAtLine = strLastFileLastLineChecked
        If bStartFromScratch <> true then
                sStatus = sStatus & "<li>Continuing search from line " & intStartAtLine & "</li>" & vbcrlf
        End If  
ElseIf strFileCreateDate <> strLastFileCheckedCreateDate or bStartFromScratch = true Then

        intStartAtLine = 0
        If bStartFromScratch <> true then
                sStatus = sStatus & "<li>File created date has changed, starting search from line 0</li>" & vbcrlf
        End If
End If

i = 0
Dim strNextLine

For each strItem in arrTextToScanFor
        strArrayToString = strArrayToString & delim & strItem
        delim = ","
Next


Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileToRead, ForReading)

Do While objTextFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
      If i < CInt(intStartAtLine) Then
        objTextFile.skipline
      Else
        'MsgBox i
        strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
        For each strItem in arrTextToScanFor
                If InStr(LCase(strNextLine),LCase(strItem)) Then
                        strResults = "<span style='font-family:courier-new;color:#696969'><span style='font-weight:bold;background-color:#BEF3F3'>Line " & i & ":</span> " & replace(lcase(strNextLine),lcase(strItem),"<span style='background-color:#FFFF81'>" & strItem & "</span>") & "</span><br>" & vbcrlf & strResults
                        bSendMail = true
                End If
        Next
      End If   
      i = i + 1

Loop
objTextFile.close

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Let's save our settings for next time.
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\RDScripts\CheckTXTFile\" & searchkey & "\FileChecked", FileToRead, "REG_SZ"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\RDScripts\CheckTXTFile\" & searchkey & "\CreateDate", strFileCreateDate, "REG_SZ"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\RDScripts\CheckTXTFile\" & searchkey & "\LastLineChecked", i, "REG_SZ"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\RDScripts\CheckTXTFile\" & searchkey & "\LastScanned", Now, "REG_SZ"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\RDScripts\CheckTXTFile\" & searchkey & "\CheckForString",strArrayToString, "REG_SZ"
set WshShell = nothing

    strFileSummary                          = "<tr><td style='font-family:calibri;font-weight:bold;color:darkblue;width:200px'>File path:</td><td>" & FileToRead & "</td></tr>"
strFileCreateDateSummary        = "<tr><td style='font-family:calibri;font-weight:bold;color:darkblue;width:200px'>Created date:</td><td>" & strFileCreateDate & "</td></tr>"
strFileModifiedDateSummary      = "<tr><td style='font-family:calibri;font-weight:bold;color:darkblue;width:200px'>Modified date:</td><td>" & strFileModifiedDate & "</td></tr>"
strArraySummary                         = "<tr><td style='font-family:calibri;font-weight:bold;color:darkblue;width:200px'>Text string(s):</td><td>" & strArrayToString & "</td></tr>"
strFileLineSummary                      = "<tr><td style='font-family:calibri;font-weight:bold;color:darkblue;width:200px'>Last line checked:</td><td>" & i & "</td></tr>"
strSummary                                      = strFileSummary & strFileCreateDateSummary & strFileModifiedDateSummary & strArraySummary & strFileLineSummary
strBodyContent                          = "<table style='font-family:calibri;'>" & strSummary & "</table><br><br><span style='font-size:large;'>Entries:</span><br>" & strResults & "<div style='padding-top:30px;font-size:x-small'><br><div style='font-weight:bold;font-family:calibri;color:black;'>Job Details:<ul style='font-weight:normal;font-family:calibri;color:darkgray;'>" & sStatus & "</ul></div></div>"
on error goto 0

'Send the email if need be.
If bSendMail = true Then Call sendmail(strMailFrom,strMailTo,strSubject,strBodyContent)

'------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Function EmailFile - email the warning file
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function SendMail(strFrom,strTo,strSubject,strMessage)
Dim iMsg, iConf, Flds
On Error GoTo 0

'//  Create the CDO connections.
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConf.Fields


'//  SMTP server configuration.
With Flds
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort

    '//  Set the SMTP server address here.
   .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = strSMTPServer
    .Update
End With

'//  Set the message properties.
With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To       = strMailTo
        .From     = strMailFrom
        .Subject  = strSubject
        .htmlbody = strMessage
End With

'iMsg.HTMLBody = strMessage

'//  Send the message.

iMsg.Send ' send the message.

If CStr(err.number) <> 0 Then

Else

End If
End Function
```

Comment: Have two ideas. 1) Use FileSystemObject to check `DateLastModified` of every file then keep the name with most recent one. 2) Starting from date of `Date()`, check if a file based on your file pattern for that date exists, go back 1 day to check if not found. The efficiency will depend on number of files in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit easier if your log files were named `filename1.yymmdd`.

Nevertheless, we can use a regex to not only verify the filename but also swap the date components to put them in our desired format!

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^(filename1\.)(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objFile In fso.GetFolder("d:\log").Files
    If re.Test(objFile.Name) Then
        strCompareName = re.Replace(objFile.Name, "$1$4$2$3")
        If strCompareName > strLatest Then strLatest = strCompareName
    End If
Next

' Switch the name back...
strLatest = re.Replace(strLatest, "$1$3$4$2")
WScript.Echo "The latest file is: " & strLatest
```

This line:

```
strCompareName = re.Replace(objFile.Name, "$1$4$2$3")
```

changes the format from `mmddyy` to `yymmdd` and saves it in a string for comparison.

Once we've finished our comparisons, we just need to take the latest file we found and reverse the process:

```
 strLatest = re.Replace(strLatest, "$1$3$4$2")
```

to get the original filename back!

Comment: Thank you Bond for your script. It feteches the latest file in folder and it prints. Am still learning VB script, i would like to know how to read the latest file which is feteched by your script, as of the script i am using FileToRead in which i have to point to a specific file so that "error" messages will be fetched and notified through an email. Is there anyway that i can read the latest file from your script?  Thanks

Comment: This statement will read an entire file (as text) into a string: `strText = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\somefile.txt").ReadAll`

Comment: Thanks Again Bond. The above statement does read a specific file. I would like to read the latest file in the folder which is feteched by your early script. Is there any way that i could add it to my original script?  For example strLatetest feteches the latest and it prints the filename, can i open the file which is fetched in strLatest? Thanks

Comment: Just replace `c:\somefile.txt` with your file path: `strText = fso.OpenTextFile("d:\log\" & strLatest).ReadAll`